# Trezor issue - "The bitcore server does not reply. Cannot connect to wallet"

Tags: bitcore, trezor

I bought a Trezor, installed everything, and sent some BTC to my wallet. Everything was working correctly. Then today, after not using the Trezor for a few days, I tried to connect and am unable to. After connecting the Trezor and putting the password in, I have a constant error message that says the bitcore server does not seem to reply, please select another server (as in screenshot). What does it mean and what should I do to connect to my wallet? It is the first time something like this has happened.

[image: message The bitcore server does not seem to reply. Please select another server[1]]

Answer (score 2):

Try the other servers.

This means Trezor's blockchain explorers (for example, this one: https://btc-bitcore3.trezor.io) are under maintenance, or restarting, or can't be connected (DNS/ISP problems)...

If your Trezor can't connect to Trezor's servers, then it won't be able to make transaction (as it'll be unable to find older transactions, unspent outputs). Try the other servers. If it still doesn't work, contact Trezor support.

Answer (score 0):

change currency backend to block explorer may fix the problem, I tried and it fixed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?  Answers are better when they explain *why* a fix works.  Better answers get more upvotes :)

Comment: If anyone can explain why this answer is correct, and why it fixes the asker's issue, please feel free to use this seed of an answers to write a better one.

Comment: Answer from @MCCCS explains the same thing in more detail.